# What is the impact of enabling the critical update 'Route My Domains Through Salesforce Edge'?

Tags: security, custom-domain, mydomain, critical-update, edge

Based on the documentation, it'll use Machine Learning to improve connectivity and performance --> so is this going to switch Salesforce login by default to Edge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce could have done a better job explaining this (and picking a less problematic way to brand it). From the comments, it's worth noting that this will be enabled for everyone using "My Domain" on 2020-07-13, and you are being given the option to enable it early.

When talking about "Edge" and *web stuff*, I wouldn't blame people for thinking they're talking about Microsoft's Edge browser, but that's not what they're talking about.

For people who have some networking experience (as in computer networks), "edge" has a different meaning<sup>1</sup>. Salesforce isn't really talking about this either though.

In addition to [the release notes for this critical update](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_security_route_edge_my_domain_cruc.htm), there's a [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) to explain what Salesforce Edge is

Quoting from that help page

> ### What is Salesforce Edge?
>
> Salesforce Edge delivers an enhanced user experience, consistent quality content delivery, and improved download times for users from across the globe. It does this by redirecting requests to the closest Salesforce location where Salesforce Edge is deployed. It provides a range of services that include TLS termination, Static Caching, and TCP optimizations. The application delivers data using the Salesforce infrastructure which protects, uses, and processes data appropriately and in accordance with the law. With Salesforce Edge, you can continue to get the same trusted infrastructure while also receiving these improved benefits.

### In normal human language

To put it in more standard words, Salesforce is deploying their own CDN (content delivery network) with special A.I. sauce to cash in on a tired buzzword. This goes beyond the normal region-based datacenter thing they've been doing for years. If you have *myDomain* enabled, it'll try to serve your requests from the nearest CDN node. This should make things faster<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1: An "edge" device is one that sits at the *edge* of a network (as opposed to a core or access device). An edge device is generally one that will end up talking to devices outside of your own network. If you have a wifi router in your home that needs to be connected to a modem, that modem would be an "edge" device (not 100% accurate, but good enough for us).</sup>
<sup>2: By "faster", I mostly mean lower latency (the time between when you make a request, and when data first starts showing up). You may or may not notice requests completing faster, because that depends on how fast each network segment between you and Salesforce is (including the download speed you get from your ISP). Latency can be a factor if multiple requests are being made (which is likely the case).</sup>

Comment: I think it's worth noting that, for anyone that has My Domain already, Salesforce Edge routing is going to be auto-activated on July 13th, 2020. You just have the opportunity to enable it early.

Comment: Is there a list of edge locations?

Comment: It seems this is not auto-enabled. Do anyone know the reason?

Comment: September 2023: I got a mail from Salesforce that Edge for our org will be enabled in December 2023.

Answer (score -1):

You should keep in mind that the TLS connection will be terminated at the nearest data center based on your location. After this the payload is encrypted again and will be redirected to your destination data center. That means you lose the end-to-end encryption! It's very strange: On https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1 it is written: "Public Cloud and Salesforce Government Cloud orgs are currently excluded from the move to Salesforce Edge.". So you can ask yourself: Why?!

Comment: A TLS/SSL termination proxy exists to offload the work of unencrypting data so that the main server doesn't have to because there can be some back and forth between the client and server to negotiate a connection. The assumption being that once you're inside Salesforce's network then the unencrypted data is as secure as it would be on the main server. GovCloud is excluded for the same reason why GovCloud isn't available in all regions: the data center needs to be equipped to meet FedRAMP, FIPS, and DoD risk and compliance standards and it's not worth it to upgrade all of them to the standards.

Comment: Maybe. I wonder if the proxy isn't just a facility to tap datas.

Comment: That makes no sense. The data is already housed on their infrastructure. They already have it.