# Clarification around Salesforce Edge Network

Tags: mydomain, network, edge

Apologies if this has been answered before or is too broad, but our company wanted to explore our options implementing the ‘Salesforce Edge Network’. As you can see from the screenshot below, we do have myDomain enabled, but this setting is **NOT** enabled under our Production My Domain settings.

[image: edgeSFDCscreenshot]

What I found interesting, is that the following article states that this perhaps was auto-activated on July 13, 2020. Can anyone shed some light on this discrepancy?
[Route My Domains Through Salesforce Edge (Previously Released Critical Update)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_route_edge_my_domain_cruc.htm&type=5&release=224)

I have identified this historic stackExchange article, which was helpful - but I was hoping to use this post to bring this discussion back to life: [What is the impact of enabling the critical update 'Route My Domains Through Salesforce Edge'?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308998/what-is-the-impact-of-enabling-the-critical-update-route-my-domains-through-sal)

We are a worldwide organization with users physically located across the globe and wanted to turn this feature on, especially if it would help page load time.

We will obviously turn this on in one of our Sandboxes but does anyone have any experience or know of any gotchas/implications of turning this on? The documentation links below are lacking clarity to our group and the fact that is feature is irreversible (outside of contact SFDC support), is a bit concerning to us.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.domain_name_edge_network.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_security_domains_edge.htm&type=5&release=230
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&type=1&language=en_US&mode=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The article stating auto-activation on July 13th, 2020 I think is being clever with the word "activation". The docs around this have changed quite a bit especially with timing.

From our experience, I "accepted" the update manually in June 2020 in a sandbox to test and realized that it meant nothing other than you were in a queue to be updated whenever they picked your org (on a rolling basis). I knew this fact based on a support case and some options listed in the [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000350511&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) (HTTP Headers) for checking whether your domain was using Edge Service (it wasn't). Support had to manually turn it on for me to test officially.

Now, there's that nice checkbox you put in your screenshot since Spring '21 that lets you know whether you're on it or not without the need to put in a case.

> In Spring '21, check the My Domain page in Setup. In the Routing section, it says "This org uses Salesforce Edge Network." If your qualifying org isn't on Salesforce Edge Network, you can enable it here.

Otherwise, you can use the below method which is what I used pre-Spring '21.

> View the HTTP headers for the org. Log in to the org. In your browser's URL bar, enter .my.salesforce.com/smth.jsp (where  is the My Domain for your org). For orgs with Salesforce Edge Network enabled, you will see the HTTP header X-Salesforce-VIP : EDGE.

We were switched to Edge Service a couple months after I accepted the critical update (a month or so before Spring '21 - so well after that July date) in production, but we didn't really know until weeks after the fact as they don't alert you or anything so now, with the checkbox, you should have more control. I was told, by support, that the switch is seamless in that one second your traffic is routing one way and the next request is then going through the Edge Service. There should be no downtime/impact in that regard.

In terms of what it'll show when it's activated, below is what I see under "Routing" for My Domain

[image]

---

*Issues*

1. I see this one [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JipYQAS) about connection timeouts/latency,
   but in discussion with support it seemed very sporadic and doesn't mean your org will run into this
   issue. Testing in a sandbox with any integrations should help see if this applies and, for us, it didn't.
2. Make sure to take a look at which [Salesforce IP Addresses and Domains to Allow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1) if you have a firewall. This gets updated (and there's a changelog at the bottom) and is an important first step to make sure you're up-to-date before activating Edge Service

*Benefits*

Definitely saw an increase in experience with our global users (particularly, Asia). Otherwise, as I said above, we didn't even know Salesforce had switched us over as at that time it was kind of whenever they switched your org over kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you. This is better info than anything our group has seen and has allowed us to go forward to enable. Thanks also for posting the known issue, we'll keep an eye on it and submit a case heaven forbid we see timeouts and large latency issues.